# Unreachable code detected string Speech = e.Result.Text;

Tags: c#

I have this problem:

http://s28.postimg.org/x8gb3pvkb/Capture.png
This is google search code via voice:

```
string Speech = e.Result.Text;
if (Speech == "I WANT TO SEARCH SOMETHING")
  {
    QEvent = Speech;
    JARVIS.SpeakAsync("what do you want to search");
    Speech = string.Empty;
  }
 else if (Speech != string.Empty && QEvent == "I WANT TO SEARCH SOMETHING")
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com/search?q=" + Speech);
     QEvent = string.Empty;

     ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 4);
     if (ranNum == 1) { JARVIS.SpeakAsync("Alright, I am searching " + Speech + " in google"); }
     else if (ranNum == 2) { JARVIS.SpeakAsync("ok sir, I am searching " + Speech); }
     else if (ranNum == 3) { JARVIS.SpeakAsync("Alright, I am searching "); }
     Speech = string.Empty;

   }
```

And in error list show me this error:

```
Unreachable code Detected
```

Can you tell me why this is unreachable code?

Comment: what line was the error on?

Comment: Ah, saw the screenshot, you have to close the switch right before your code that is pasted above.

Comment: You forgot to close your `switch` with a `}`

Comment: Why would you post different code in the question than in the screen shot?  The error you specify isn't in the code posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the switch

```
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case "open":
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        break;
    default:
        //do something 
        break;
}
string Speech = e.Result.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this error happens because you didn't close your switch statement as you showed on your image. Since this happens because of swithc, the code you posted is irrelevant.

You used `break;` in your `case: "Open"`, your `string Speech = e.Result.Text;` line is unreachable.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t.aspx);

> Execution of the statement list in the selected switch section begins
>   with the first statement and proceeds through the statement list,
>   typically **until a jump statement, such as a break, goto case, return,
>   or throw, is reached**. At that point, control is transferred outside
>   the switch statement or to another case label.

```
switch (expr)
{
    ...
    case "Open":
         SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
         break;
}
string Speech = e.Result.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it shows that you have put code after `break`, so those lines will not be executed because, all code after `break` will be skipped, that is why it showing `Unreachable code`.

So either you need to put `break` after those code blocks or remove those code blocks and place after `switch-case`.